# URL in-browser DELETE link (rather than GET)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, devise, get, routes

I have a Rails 4 app and I'm using Devise. Everything is set up correctly, I just have a question about URLs and links.

My devise model is called "clients". When I navigate to /clients/sign_out (i.e. I type that in the address bar) I get the following error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/clients/sign_out"
```

Now, I understand why I'm getting this error – the link is to a DELETE, not a GET.

Obviously, one way to log out is to use this link:

```
= link_to "Log Out", destroy_client_session_path, method: :delete
```

(that is haml, btw).

However, I'm looking for a URL to type into the address bar that will effectively make a DELETE, not GET call. This is more of a possibility question than a practicality question – I'd appreciate any insight on the matter!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to enter a URL into the address bar and have it perform a DELETE request. If you would like to destroy the session by visiting a url, you can change the following Devise configuration in `config/initializers/devise.rb` to the following

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Please note that this approach isn't RESTful as `POST` and `DELETE` should be used when changing state.

Comment: Thanks for the response — do you know the rationale behind not being able to do so? Is it a security thing?

Comment: That's just the way browsers are designed - any URI typed into the address bar will perform a `GET` request. There are developer add-ons/extensions you can download that will allow you to make `POST/PUT/DELETE/PATCH` requests if that's something you're looking to do. On Chrome you can use _Postman - REST Client_ which works really well.